# Reliable driver for GeForce 6200 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia

I installed Nvidia driver V304.132 from Synaptic, latest available last month, to run GeForce 6200TC PCI card with Ubuntu 16.04.  Ubuntu running fine Until I installed driver and card, then continual request to login with screen looping.  I could get into shell but all solutions found did not work, and so assume must be driver fault.  Is there a generic driver proven to work for instance?

Comment: You maybe want to try out the nouveau driver and in that case you need to remove the Nvidia proprietary driver. From what you wrote, I understand the nouveau (by default installed) driver was active before you installed the proprietary driver, right?

Comment: Thanks, but where do I find Nouveau?  Can't bring it up in synaptic or ubuntu software

Comment: It's installed by default, with the Linux kernel. You just don't need to do anything if you haven't the Nvidia driver installed, otherwise you need to remove the Nvidia driver.

Answer (score 1):

The GeForce 6200TC PCI card seems to be 10-12 years old. There might be problems to find a good proprietary driver for it in the newest Ubuntu versions. Try the free driver *nouveau* as described in the comment by Gustaf. If it will make Ubuntu too slow, I suggest that you try a flavour of Ubuntu with a *lighter desktop environment*, for example Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu. See this link and links from it,

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)